# Random image with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, random, repeat

Without knowing javascript at all I somehow created random image generator:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!-- 
document.write("<img src=\"image-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1)+".jpg\" />");
//--></script>
```

I does show random images as it should but there are some limitations so I need your help.

1. Sometimes I have more than 9 images for some pages and their name is "mad-01", "mad-02"... "mad-11" to keep them sorted but code above can't show images with 0 before second digit. I have named images with and without 0 before second digit: "mad-01", "calm-1". How can this be solved? Or is it better to just remove 0 from images?
2. Is there a way to make this code that way so I won't need to keep writing how many images is there to show?

I would like to have this code as shortest as possible that's why I'm not using array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would say removing the 0 from the file names would be the easiest solution. Depends on whether you need it or not.
2. Not sure what you mean here. JavaScript can't detect how many images there are in the file system on its own. If you're using some kind of server side language it might have functionality for counting files, and then you could print that value into the JavaScript code.

---

If you want to keep the leading zeros in the file names, you could something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!-- 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
if(number < 10) number = "0" + number;
document.write("<img src=\"image-"+number+".jpg\" />");
//--></script>
```

Comment: 1. It's not someting that is really need but would be good to have. 2. I see. So I can skip this.

Comment: Updated answer with suggestion on how to handle leading zeros.

Comment: Thank you for respone. With your code now it works only if image have 2 digits, with 1 it isn't working because it always try to input 0 before 1 digit images.

Comment: Well, yes, that was the whole point. The JavaScript code doesn't know whether the image names contains leading 0's or not, so you have to choose what you want. If you want to keep your own code, you have to remove leading 0's from the file names. If you want to keep leading 0's you have to use my code, and all file names must have leading 0's if the number is 1-9.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was suspecting that and now I'm sure. I will stick to my code. I appreciate your help. Thank you.